# Generating the RGBF color

Tags: colors, hex, rgb

I need to generate the RGB(Filter) which is RGBF shortcut color, which numbers are totally different as of the simple RGB color, just take a look at this `aliceblue` color example:

RGBF:
`0.941176, 0.972549, 1.000000, 1.000000`

RGB equivalent:
`240,248,255`

HEX equivalent:
`F0F8FF`

The question is - how can I generate the RGBF color from HEX or RGB? I have been google'd quite a bit but it seems like this topic (`RGBF` color) is not popular at all.

Comment: What does the 4th item in the RGBF relate to? From what I can tell, that 4 item relates to either  'emerald' or 'cyan' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBE_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the 4th term in your RGBF sequence is but the other 3 just look like the result of division:

```
0.941176 = 240/255
0.972549 = 248/255
1.000000 = 255/255
```

Comment: The 4th term is the `Filter` whats why its called RGBF(ilter). Your answer makes sense! Thank you :)